# What's the difference between "be up to" and "get up to"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Recently, I know the Word "get up to".
It just means "do something."
But I still don't understand the difference between "be up to" and "get up to".

For example,
When I want to ask what you did yesterday, I say

```
What were you up to yesterday?
=What did you get up to yesterday?
```

When I want to ask what you're doing right now, I say

```
What are you up to now?
=What are you getting up to now?
```

When I haven't seen you for a long time and ask what you have been doing recently, I say

```
What have you been up to?
=What have you been getting up to?
```

When I want to ask what you're gonna do tomorrow, I say

```
What are you up to tomorrow?
=What do you get up to tomorrow?
```

Am I right?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Cambridge Dictionary [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-up-to-sth) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-up-to-sth):

> be up to *sth* = to be doing something:
>
> - What are you up to at the moment?

and

> get up to *sth* = to do something, **often something that other people would disapprove of**:
>
> - She's been getting up to all sorts of **mischief** lately.
> - I wonder what those two got up to yesterday?

So the use of **to get up to *sth*** implies a bad intention / deed, unlike **to be up to *sth***.

@RonaldSole correctly adds in the comment (thank you):

> to be up to *sth* = is also used in the sense of **be capable of**.
>
> - Will he be up to a long walk so soon after his operation?

Comment: **Be up- to** is also used in the sense of **be capable of**. Will he be up to a long walk so soon after his operation?

Comment: I still don't get it. I know "get up to sth" is used to sometimes express something that you shouldn't do. But actually "get up to sth" is used instead of "do sth".  I've  checked Cambridge Dictionary. There're some examples that use "get up to" instead of "do" . For example, What have you been getting up to?. Sometimes I hear "What have you been up to?". That's why I'm asking the difference "be up to" and "get up to". Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mashall: your observation is good. The two "words" can mean the same thing sometimes. But in those times, a broader context is needed, and other factors like intonation, gestures... are also important.

Answer (score 0):

Idiom Definition 1 [image]
"up to"

```
occupied with, especially devising or scheming
```

Idiom Definition 2 [image]
"up to"

```
able to do or deal with
```

Idiom Definition 3 [image] "up to"

```
dependent on
```

Idiom Definition 4  "up to"

```
as far as or approaching a certain point
```

[For more information on "up to"](http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/up-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

"Get up to" would translate to what did you accomplish. "be up to" translates to what are you planning on accomplishing.